# Music Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am a startup `mysql` learner, and wants to design a music database with the using normalization rules.

We have a `track table` who stores details about `tracks` like `track_id, track_name, artist_name` etc. but also i want to create a `playlist` table where one track will be belongs to more than one playlist, so how can i design such type of database.

`track_table( track_id, track_title, album_id )
album_table( album_id, album_name, total_track )
playlist( plyalist_id, playlist_name, track_ids )`

Should i use above approach where the `track_ids` will be something like this : `101, 102, 103, 104, 105`, but i think this is not a good idea because with the `php` as a server side it will little bit slow. becuase we have to use `implode` and `looping` to get the list of all `track_title`.

If anybody wants to help. i really appreciate that.

`

Comment: Sounds ok. The design should be independent of the DBMS. If it's badly optimized, it's not your fault. Your job is to design a consistent and logical schema.

Comment: The same track can sometimes appear on more than one album. So, I'd use a junction table (track,album) instead.

Comment: In addition to being a startup mysql user, are you a startup database designer?  If so, I suggest you learn the fundamentals first.  The fundamentals are not obvious, but they can be learned.  There's a good list of references in an answer to a previous question.  If I can locate that question, I'll pass it on.

Answer (score 0):

This idea is not very "relational" in the sense of relational database design. I think you should have the playlist items in its own table

```
playlist_item(playlist_id, album_id, track_id)
```

That is, if track_id is not unique!

Storing the track_ids in a set as you suggest is then not needed. No need to implode or such in your php code. Just one more `JOIN`.

A general advice: Use always a simple primary key in each table. Add natural keys as needed as indexes and/or to create constraints.

Comment: Hopefully the track_id is the primary key on the track table, so album_id can be removed from the playlist_item table. You'd probably want a play_order column as well.

Comment: i would give each table a generic primary key column named "id", but it seems the OP lost interest already.

Answer (score 0):

Playlist to track is a "many-to-many" relationship, so you need a table in between:

```
playlist( plyalist_id, playlist_name)
playlist_tracks (playlist_id, track_id, sequence)
```

`sequence` is 1,2,... (assuming you want the playlist to play in a certain order).

```
CREATE TABLE playlist_tracks (
    playlist_id ...,
    track_id ...,
    sequence TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(playlist_id, sequence),  -- for playing them
    INDEX(track_id)   -- in case you want to see which playlists contain a particular track
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```